# Trying to get datas for last three months

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any general query for getting last three months data or to get data from 'x' month to 'y' month?

I am new to mysql. I need assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last 3 months from current date:

```
select * from table where 
timestamp >= now()-interval 3 month;
```

Last 3 months Starting with first of month:

```
select * from table where 
timestamp >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 3 month;
```

Get Previous 3 months

```
select * from table where 
month(timestamp) < month(now()) and
timestamp >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 4 month;
```